# How to load_files and process a .txt file with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

Let's say that I have in a folder in the desktop with different .txt files. They look like this.

File_1:

```
('this', 'is'), ('a', 'very'),....., ('large', '.txt'), ('file', 'with'), ('lots', 'of'), ('words', 'like'), ('this', 'i'), ('would', 'like'), ('to', 'create'), ('a', 'matrix'),'LABEL_1'
```

**...**

File_N:

```
('this', 'is'), ('a', 'another'),....., ('large', '.txt'), ('file', 'with'), ('lots', 'of'), ('words', 'like'), ('this', 'i'), ('would', 'like'), ('to', 'create'), ('a', 'matrix'),'LABEL_N'
```

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html), scikit-learn provide `load_files`, I can vectorize with the hashing trick as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import FeatureHasher
from sklearn.svm import SVC

training_data = [[('string1', 'string2'), ('string3', 'string4'),
                  ('string5', 'string6'), 'POS'],
                 [('string1', 'string2'), ('string3', 'string4'), 'NEG']]

feature_hasher_vect = FeatureHasher(input_type ='string')

X = feature_hasher_vect.transform(((' '.join(x) for x in sample)
                                        for sample in training_data))

print X.toarray()
```

output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

How can I vectorize (apply the same procedure above) to the whole .txt folder with `load_files()` or any other method?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with skikit-learn, which may have something better, but you could do what you describe if the files are in the format shown using something relatively simple as illustrated by the following function:

```
import ast
import glob
import os

def my_load_files(folder, pattern):
    pathname = os.path.join(folder, pattern)
    for filename in glob.glob(pathname):
        with open(filename) as file:
            yield ast.literal_eval(file.read())

text_folder = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Samples'
print [[' '.join(x) for x in sample]
                        for sample in my_load_files(text_folder, 'File_*')]
```

Note: Since there's a label at the end of each file (and your`training_data`), you might want to use the following instead which would leave it out of what is passed to the `feature_hasher_vect.transform()` method:

```
print [[' '.join(x) for x in sample[:-1]]
                        for sample in my_load_files(text_folder, 'File_*')]
```